how to use resources with maven
I created a Maven project to use JavaFX.
I have two folders:

src/main/java/application containing my source code.
src/main/resources which must contain the resources.

I found some Java code that loads an fxml file. But when I drop the fxml
file into src/main/resources, and I run with mvn javafx:run, I have this
error that tells me that it does not find the fxml file. Yet in my
pom.xml there is the link to the resources:
build>
<sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
<resources>
<resource>
<directory>src/main/resources</directory>
<includes>
<include>*</include>

</includes>
</resource>
</resource>

but when I put the fxml in src/main/java/application it works so how to make it found by maven.
here is my pom.xml file :
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fr.miminbat</groupId>
    <artifactId>cryptor-miminbat</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cryptor</name>
    
    <!-- Propriétés pour la version de JavaFX et les noms des classes principales -->
    <properties>
        <javafx.version>13</javafx.version>
        <launcher.main>Launcher</launcher.main>
        <main.gui>Main</main.gui>
    </properties>
    
    <!-- Dépendances pour JavaFX Controls et JavaFX FXML -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <!-- Configuration pour le répertoire source -->
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
               <includes>
                <include>*</include> 

            </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        
        <!-- Plugins Maven -->
        <plugins>
            <!-- Plugin pour la compilation Maven avec dépendances 
             <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>21</release> <!-- Version de Java -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <!-- Plugin pour lancer l'application JavaFX -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>application.${main.gui}</mainClass> <!-- Classe principale pour JavaFX -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <!-- Plugin pour exécuter l'application JavaFX avec mvn exec:java -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>application.${main.gui}</mainClass> <!-- Classe principale pour lancer l'application -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <!-- Plugin pour créer un JAR exécutable avec les dépendances -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>application.${launcher.main}</mainClass> <!-- Classe principale pour le manifeste -->
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- Exécuter lors de la phase 'package' -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



And my Java code:
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        URL fxmlLocation = getClass().getResource("/login.fxml");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlLocation);
        Parent root = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        // 400, 300
        String css = this.getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm();
        
        scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
        
        
       
        

        stage.setTitle("Login Application");
        Image icon = new Image("icon.png");
        stage.getIcons().add(icon);
        stage.setWidth(400);
        stage.setHeight(600);
        stage.setResizable(true);
        stage.setFullScreen(false);
        
       // stage.setFullScreenExitHint("for exit presse 'echap' ");
       // stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.valueOf("g"));
       
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}



here is the error I get when I do mvn javafx:run :
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< fr.miminbat:cryptor-miminbat >--------------------
[INFO] Building cryptor 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> javafx:0.0.8:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ cryptor-miminbat >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ cryptor-miminbat ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ cryptor-miminbat ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< javafx:0.0.8:run (default-cli) < process-classes @ cryptor-miminbat <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- javafx:0.0.8:run (default-cli) @ cryptor-miminbat ---
juil. 13, 2024 1:46:42 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
AVERTISSEMENT: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 22 by JavaFX runtime of version 13
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1125)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:618)
        at application.Main.start(Main.java:31)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1117)
        ... 11 more
Exception running application application.Main
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (JavaFXRunMojo.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:903)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:280)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:203)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:314)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:567)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:434)
        at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:75)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:162)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:903)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:280)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:203)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:201)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:361)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:314)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.154 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-07-13T13:46:43+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.8:run (default-cli) on project cryptor-miminbat: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException


Line 31 of "Main.java" fails attempting to construct an Image using the url parameter "icon.png". Where is "icon.png"?

"I have this error that tells me that it does not find the fxml file". No, from the error it is clear that it can find the FXML file, otherwise it would not reach the line that is throwing the exception.

This is the problem: document with JavaFX API of version 22 by JavaFX runtime of version 13... also do not use the maven-assembly-plugin to package a javafx application. There exists a javafx-maven-plugin for that purpose...

And furthermore src/main/java/application is application a package name? And src/main/resources is the default in Maven so no need to configure that... as well as src/main/java is the source code location and src/test/java is the location for test code...

Potentially naive comment -- I'm not a Java programmer -- but in your pom excerpt you open <resources> plural, then <resource> singular, but then you close </resource> singular twice. Is this a typo or a red herring?

@joanis That error is only present in the snippet, not in the complete pom.xml, so I think it’s safe to assume it’s just a typo in the question, not the actual code.

Possible duplicate: How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?

Study: Eden coding Where to put resource files in JavaFX
